# How to add tooltip for SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My teacher ask me to show a tooltip on SVG circle which have some links and some information when we mouse over the circle. And they give me the tip to use jQuery UI. But I have searched a lot about this sort of tooltip, seriously nothing seems to be able to help me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service, please show your efforts

Comment: Why is this tagged C++?

Answer (score 2):

```
.priority-order svg{
    float: right;
    margin-left: -25px;
}

/*tooltips green color dot*/

a.tooltips {
  position: relative;
  right: 5px;
  float: right;
}

a.tooltips span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #5FB336;
  height: 29px;
  line-height: 29px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
a.tooltips span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  width: 0; height: 0;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #5FB336;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}
a:hover.tooltips span {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 50px;
  left: 30%;
  margin-left: -57px;
  z-index: 999;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*tooltips1 blue color dot*/

a.tooltips1 {
  position: relative;
  right: 5px;
  float: right;
}

a.tooltips1 span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #3166ff;
  height: 29px;
  line-height: 29px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
a.tooltips1 span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  width: 0; height: 0;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #3166ff;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}
a:hover.tooltips1 span {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 50px;
  left: 30%;
  margin-left: -57px;
  z-index: 999;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*tooltips1 red color dot*/

a.tooltips2 {
  position: relative;
  right: 5px;
  float: right;
}

a.tooltips2 span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #f0584f;
  height: 29px;
  line-height: 29px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
a.tooltips2 span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  width: 0; height: 0;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #f0584f;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}
a:hover.tooltips2 span {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 50px;
  left: 30%;
  margin-left: -57px;
  z-index: 999;
  cursor: pointer;
}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
                <div class="priority-order">

                      <div class="">
<a class="right tooltips" href="#"><svg height="40" width="100" class="">
              <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="10" stroke-width="3" fill="#5fb336" />
                <span>Clear</span>
    </svg></a>
                    </div>  

                     <div class="">
<a class="right tooltips1" href="#"><svg height="40" width="100" class="">
              <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="10" stroke-width="3" fill="#3166ff" />
                <span>Issue</span>
    </svg></a>   
                    </div>


                <div class="">
<a class="right tooltips2" href="#"><svg height="40" width="100" class="">
              <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="10" stroke-width="3" fill="#f0584f" />
                <span>Alert</span>
    </svg></a>   
                    </div>

            </div>
            </div>
```

I created custom tooltip of my own by CSS. This research took me one day to complete the task.